# Dynamic ViewModel's bound values becomes null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I followed few online tutorials to switch between dynamic views from a ListView.

1. In my MainWindow, I have a ListView in the left pane with ItemsSource of list of sub ViewModels. (Each sub ViewModel implements an Interface)
2. Each ViewModel have its own View as a DataTemplate.
3. I'm calling the GenerateReport() method of the selected view from the MainWindow. But the values of selected views becomes null.

Download my source from [Github](https://github.com/mathikp/WPFDynamicViews).

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Run the application and type text in the Students Report's Id and Name. (The breakpoints in StudentReportViewModels's properties are properly hitting and values updated.)
2. Then click Generate Report button. The StudentReportViewModels's properties values becomes null.

How to fix the issue? Please help.

Source:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StudentsReportViewModel}">
        <view:StudentsReport/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MarksReportViewModel}">
        <view:MarksReport />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReport, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="5" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedReport.ViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Content="Generate Report" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding GenerateReportCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _generateReportCommand;

    private Report selectedReport;
    public Report SelectedReport
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedReport;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.selectedReport)
            {
                this.selectedReport = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Report> Reports { get; set; }

    public ICommand GenerateReportCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_generateReportCommand == null)
            {
                _generateReportCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    p => GenerateReport()
                    );
            }

            return _generateReportCommand;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Reports = new List<Report>
        {
            new Report{ Name = "Students Report", ViewModel = new StudentsReportViewModel()},
            new Report{ Name = "Marks Report", ViewModel = new MarksReportViewModel()}
        };

        SelectedReport = Reports[0];
    }

    public void GenerateReport()
    {
        SelectedReport.ViewModel.GenerateReport();
    }
}
```

StudentsReport.xaml

```
<TextBox Height="25" Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Height="25" Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

StudentsReportViewModel:

```
public class StudentsReportViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IReportViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.id)
            {
                this.id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.name)
            {
                this.name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public StudentsReportViewModel()
    {

    }

    public void GenerateReport()
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"Id = {Id}, Name = {Name}");
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IReportViewModel
{
    void GenerateReport();
}
```

Model:

```
public class Report
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IReportViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should include a source code sample instead of a link to a github repository

Comment: @GlenThomas Code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your StudentsReport.xaml UserControl is binding to an instance of the StudentsReportViewModel created in the XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:StudentsReportViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The Generate Report button however is calling into another instance of the StudentsReportViewModel that is create in the MainWindowVieModel constructor and is stored in the Report class.

```
Reports = new List<Report>
{
    new Report{ Name = "Students Report", ViewModel = new StudentsReportViewModel()},
    new Report{ Name = "Marks Report", ViewModel = new MarksReportViewModel()}
};
```

You need to remove one of these instances so that the UserControl's DataContext is bound to the same view model instance that you are generating the report message from.
I suggest deleting this code from StudentsReport.xaml:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:StudentsReportViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.